# How to recover / restore an “ext4” partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I have an `ext4` formatted partition, namely `/dev/sdc1`. I did **not** format it but somehow `parted` reports this partition as an unknown file system. Is there a way to mark this partition as `ext4` again **without** formatting, so that I can try to rescue remaining files as much as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux, the partition type identifiers are almost entirely cosmetic: in particular, the filesystem repair tools certainly won't require the partition type to be correctly specified in the partition table.

If you point an `ext4` filesystem recovery tool at a partition, it will do its best to find and fix an `ext4` filesystem on it, if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised that `fsck` did the trick.

Comment: The `fsck` of the `ext2`/`3`/`4` family of filesystems is the product of more than 20 years of incremental development by now. It's pretty robust.